# nuxt sitemap - example.com/sitemap.xml not exist on Layer0 hosting

Tags: vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, sitemap, sitemap.xml

I have deployed my nuxtjs application on [Layer0](https://www.layer0.co/) using the following command `layer0 deploy --site=sample-website --environment=production`. I used [Nuxt Sitemap Module](https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/) to generate sitemap.xml for my nuxtjs app. It works fine in the dev environment (`http://127.0.0.1:3000/sitemap.xml`) but in the production environment, I cannot find it.

nuxt.config.js :

```
export default {

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
  ],


  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://sathyamolagoda.me',
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    defaults: {
      lastmod: new Date(),
      changefreq: 'weekly',
      priority: 0.8,
    },
  },
}
```

`npm run generate` will create the following file `".nuxt\dist\sitemap-routes.json"` but it is not available in the `.layer0` folder which is deployed to the production environment.
What would be the issue, have I missed anything?

Comment: Does it work if you build it locally? `yarn generate && yarn start`? Also, does it work on Netlify or you try to host there (since you're using SSG anyway)?

Comment: Yes, it works with yarn generate && yarn start. I moved with layer0 as I'm using SSR.

Comment: With `yarn generate`, you're using SSG (`target: 'static'`), not SSR (`target: 'server'`).

Comment: first of all, my application use SSR so I'm targeting `'server'`. Also, the sitemap works fine in the dev environment, especially in my local setup. but once I deploy it to layer 0 it will not work

Comment: Alright, so if you want to have it working with `target: 'server'`, you need to use `yarn build` (which is for SSR) rather than `yarn generate` (which is for SSG).

Comment: I voted to close this question because a "internal server error" is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default [layer0](https://www.layer0.co/) configuration not include `".nuxt/dist/sitemap-routes.json"` file into `.layer0` path. In order to fix this we have to add few code lines to `layer0.config.js`.

```
'use strict'

// This file was automatically added by layer0 deploy.
// You should commit this file to source control.

module.exports = {
  backends: {
    origin: {
      domainOrIp: 'layer0-origin.example.com',
    },
  },
  includeNodeModules: true,
  connector: '@layer0/nuxt',
  // include the required file
  includeFiles: {
    '.nuxt/dist/sitemap-routes.json': true,
  },
}
```

then the file will be there as below
[image]

Comment: Thanks for narrowing this down. I work at Layer0 and will have someone look into to adding this into the connector.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SSR with Nuxt, let Nuxt serve the sitemap instead of the static file you would had created with `npm run generate`. Add the following to your Layer0 router:

```js
.match('/sitemap.xml', ({ renderWithApp }) => {
  renderWithApp()
})
```

I've updated our documentation with this information: https://docs.layer0.co/guides/nuxt#serving-sitemap-with-ssr